# Angular factory function is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, factory

I'm making an API connection that I use both on my controllers, yet it seems my controllers do not recognize my factory.
Here is my factory;

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['gantt',
  'gantt.sortable',
  'gantt.movable',
  'gantt.drawtask',
  'gantt.tooltips',
  'gantt.bounds',
  'gantt.progress',
  'gantt.tree',
  'gantt.groups',
  'gantt.resizeSensor',
  'gantt.overlap'
]);
myApp.factory('Shared', function() {
  var data = {};
  var taskOnFocus = {};
  var dummy = 'abcd';
  return {
    retrieveData: function() {
      return {
        then: function(callback) {
          $.post("/planboard/RetrieveData", {}, function(ajaxResponse) {
            if (ajaxResponse) callback(JSON.parse(ajaxResponse))
            else toastr.error("Error on Retrieving Data")
          })
        }
      }
    }

  }
})

myApp.controller('here', ['$scope', 'Shared',
  function($scope, Shared) {

    Shared.RetrieveData().then(function(response) {
      $scope.data = response
    })
  }
])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

In my other controller, i also called Shared.RetrieveData() but my error includes only this part, so I guess I couldn't define my factory into the controllers well. Any suggestions?

Comment: You wrote `Shared.RetrieveData` but your factory has only `retriveData`.
Try changing `Shared.RetrieveData` to `Shared.retrieveData`

Comment: damn I'm so ashamed.  Thank for the help btw.